# Does Highchart.js not have 'stacked percentage bar' chart

Tags: highcharts

I can see that Highcharts.js provides 'stacked percentage column' charts but I cant seem to find 'stacked percentage bar' charts. Am I missing something?

stacked percentage column = https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-percent

stacked percentage bar = ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified under the [Bar chart information page](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/bar-chart) a bar chart is:

> The bar chart is exactly the same as a column chart only the x-axis and y-axis are switched.

With that in mind, we can turn any column chart into a bar chart by switching the axis. This can be done using the `inverted` option ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.inverted)).

For example ([JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/578vx0w6/2/)):

```
chart: {
    type: 'column',
    inverted: true
}
```